# Check output/result of command executed automatically from command-line by PuTTY

Tags: ssh, command-line, putty

I need to execute a remote command `start system1` in order to start a server. This is by SSHing in one of the admin IPMI boards. I'm trying to automate the process by doing this command line:

```
"c:\Program Files\Putty\putty.exe" -ssh root@192.168.0.119 22 -pw password -m C:\temp\ssh\commands.txt
```

The `command.txt` contains just this:

```
start system1
```

which when executed powers up the server. When I execute the above command line, putty starts and then the console disappears after a few seconds, probably after logging in. The command is not executed.

If I remove the `-m commands.txt`, PuTTY logs in ok.

Any ideas how I can make this work? Log in and execute...

Answer (score 0):

PuTTY is not the right too for automatic command execution.

Use [Plink (PuTTY command-line connection tool)](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter7.html). It's a console application. If you execute it from an existing console window (like `cmd.exe`), the command output will be preserved, so that you can see, what went wrong.

```
plink.exe -ssh root@192.168.0.119 22 -pw password start system1
```

Comment: I tried this and it does nothing.... meaning it thinks a bit, then goes back to command prompt.


without the start system1 at the end, logs in ok, shows up the console output. Maybe it's worth mentioning that the console output takes a while 10s to show up. Maybe that's what's going on? Times out?

I also tried -m file, same, does nothing, returns to command prompt

Comment: Try `echo start system1 | plink.exe -ssh root@192.168.0.119 22 -pw password`

Comment: Thanks for help Martin!